# How can I get the certificate without completing an ssl handshake?

Tags: java, network-programming

I have read that it is possible to get the certificates data without competing the handshake & this is desirable to reduce the time. The code below does the purpose of getting the certificate information but code completes the ssl hanndshake. If any one expert in network programming can tell me how can I get the certificate information for a remote host without completing an ssl handshake?

```
package com.kushal.security;

import java.security.cert.Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class JavaSSLCertificate {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

int port = 443;

String hostname = "gmail.com";

SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection
.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();

System.out.println("Creating a SSL Socket For "+hostname+" on port "+port);

SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(hostname, port);

socket.startHandshake();
System.out.println("Handshaking Complete");

Certificate[] serverCerts = socket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
System.out.println("Retreived Server's Certificate Chain");

System.out.println(serverCerts.length + "Certifcates Found\n\n\n");
for (int i = 0; i < serverCerts.length; i++) {
Certificate myCert = serverCerts[i];
System.out.println("====Certificate:" + (i+1) + "====");
System.out.println("-Public Key-\n" + myCert.getPublicKey());
System.out.println("-Certificate Type-\n " + myCert.getType());

System.out.println();
}

socket.close();
}

}
```

Comment: So you just want the certificates and not the key exchange? Because there's really not much else in an SSL handshake that could take up any time.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. I may need both.

Comment: If you need both, that's essentially the entirety of the SSL handshake. So I'm not sure where *"this is desirable to reduce the time"* comes from

Answer (score -1):

The certificate exchange is part of the handshake. I don't know where you read that you can get the certificate without waiting for the handshake  but it isn't true, certainly in JSSE at least. It doesn't even make sense to me.